# Mac Terminal startup error

Tags: macos, terminal, startup

When I start terminal up on mac I am getting this error:

```
-bash: user@computer:$: command not found
```

What does it mean?

I ran the following in terminal to diagnose the issue:

```
echo $PS1
\h:\W \u\$
```

Comment: What happens after that error message appears?  Do you get another command prompt (`user@computer$`)?  Does the Terminal window close immediately?  If you do have another prompt, try typing `echo $PS1` and include the result in your question.  Also, have you edited any of these files in your home directory: `.profile`, `.bash_profile`, `.bashrc`?  You may have told your shell (`bash`) to run a non-existent command when it starts up.

Comment: I installed rvm using 'sudo', and I that made some changes to my home directory, it did make some changes to the '.profile' file that I had to comment out. 
The Terminal window does not immediately close, and functions normally. There just is this normal error on startup

Comment: So the error does not appear after every prompt, but only for the first prompt you see in a shell?  That suggests the problem is in your `.profile` (maybe you missed something that `rvm` changed) *or* perhaps in your system's `/etc/profile` or `/etc/bashrc`.  If you installed using `sudo`, it may very well have changed some of the system-wide shell startup files. :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to restore .bash\_profile on a mac? None of my unix terminal are working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21067625/how-to-restore-bash-profile-on-a-mac-none-of-my-unix-terminal-are-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To determine that this is a startup file issue, try changing the shell to something other than bash.

ZSH is included with macOS. To change the shell to ZSH run:

`chsh -s /bin/zsh`

You will be prompted for your user password, once complete press `⌘N` to open a new terminal window, you will see a slightly different prompt.

If the error does not occur, then there is an issue in one of the bash startup files. Switch back over to bash with `chsh -s /bin/bash` and double check your `~/.bashrc`, `~/.profile`, and `~/.bash_profile`, as well as `/etc/bashrc` and `/etc/profile`.

If bash remains broken for you, using [ZSH](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) over Bash is always an option.